# Example of unstable group

Tags: model-theory

What are examples of unstable groups in a purely group theoretic language? It is easy with a ring theoretic language (e.g. Given $(\mathbb{Q}, +, .)$ we can define $a<b$ using a formula which allows us to prove that Th$(\mathbb{Q}, +, .)$ is unstable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $G$ a group and $g, h\in G$, write $g\le_c h$ if $$\forall x\in G, gx=xg\implies hx=xh.$$ That is, $g\le_ch$ if $g$ commutes with "fewer" elements than $h$ does.

(For example, if $g\in Z(G)$ then $g\le_ch$ for every $h\in G$.)

I believe that we can construct groups whose associated $\le_c$-preorder has infinite chains; such a group will be unstable.

---

Another example: consider the group $G$ on generators $g_i$ ($i\in\mathbb{N}$), and relations $g_ig_j^2g_i^{-3}$ for $i<j$. Unless I miss something, this group is unstable: the set of standard generators is totally ordered by the formula "$xy^2x^{-3}=e$".

Answer (score 5):

Here is another example of an unstable group: [The braid group with infinitely many generators](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239697/are-braid-groups-with-finitely-many-generators-nip). The proof on this page shows that this group is not **NIP** $\implies$ unstable.

Comment: +1 for an example of an actually *interesting* unstable group.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't not NIP be just IP though?

Comment: @dav11: You could say IP. In the literature, sometimes people say not NIP. For better or worse, I say not NIP. People also use the term "dependent" to mean NIP, and so you could also say not dependent.